# Working with GA4 data in BigQuery via PowerBI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, google-analytics-4

I’m trying to work with GA4 data stored in BigQuery via Power BI, but I’m relatively inexperienced in both and am not sure how to handle the JSON format it’s stored in.

I followed this tutorial to flatten the tables in BQ:

https://www.ga4bigquery.com/tutorial-how-to-flatten-the-ga4-bigquery-export-schema-for-relational-databases-using-unnest/

But when I query the flat tables in PowerBI, there are still nested values without labels.

The data currently looks like this:

| event_name | device | geo | traffic_source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| page_view | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"mobile"},{"v":"Huawei"},{"v":"YAL-L21"},{"v":"Honor 20"},{"v":null},{"v":"Android"},{"v":"Android 10"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":"ar-iq"},{"v":"No"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"Android Webview"},{"v":"110.0.5481.185"},{"v":"www.mypage.co.uk"}]}}]}} | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"Europe"},{"v":"Ireland"},{"v":"County Dublin"},{"v":"Dublin"},{"v":"Northern Europe"},{"v":"(not set)"}]}} | {"v":{"f":[{"v":"(organic)"},{"v":"organic"},{"v":"google"}]}} |

And my desired outcome would be to pivot them into separate columns like this:

| event_name | geo.continent | geo.sub_continent | geo.country | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| page_view | Europe | Northern Europe | Ireland |  |

Thanks in advance!